# Can't put div below relative div

Tags: css, css-position

I'm in a quite a complicated situation. First off all, I have two columns, that go under each other when the screen gets smaller. My problem is that in one of the columns I have a relative div. I want another div directly under it, but it keeps overlapping with the first div.

Here's my code:

```js
<script>
    var timer = setInterval(nextImage, 4000);
    var curImage = 0;
    var numImages = 4;

    function nextImage() {
        var e;
        // remove showMe class from current image
        e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
        removeClass(e, "showMe");

        // compute next image
        curImage++;
        if (curImage > numImages - 1) {
            curImage = 0;
        }

        // add showMe class to next image
        e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
        addClass(e, "showMe");
    }

    function addClass(elem, name) {
        var c = elem.className;
        if (c) c += " ";  // if not blank, add a space separator
        c += name;
        elem.className = c;
    }

    function removeClass(elem, name) {
        var c = elem.className;
        elem.className = c.replace(name, "").replace(/   /g, " ").replace(/^ | $/g, "");  // remove name and extra blanks
    }
</script>
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  max-width: 1750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.homepage-main-img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.homepage-main-img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #194d98;
  outline: 2px solid #0c7d5f;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide {
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

.showMe {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <div>stuff</div>
      </div>
      <div class="column container2">
        <div class="homepage-main-img-wrapper">
            <img id="slideimg0" class="slide showMe homepage-main-img" src="img/homepage-photos/1.jpg">
            <img id="slideimg1" class="slide homepage-main-img" src="img/homepage-photos/2.jpg">
            <img id="slideimg2" class="slide homepage-main-img" src="img/homepage-photos/3.jpg">
            <img id="slideimg3" class="slide homepage-main-img" src="img/homepage-photos/4.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="test">
          <div id="instagram-feed" class="instagram_feed">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/f00" style="margin:0.5% 0.5%;width:32.333333333333336%;float:left;">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/f00" style="margin:0.5% 0.5%;width:32.333333333333336%;float:left;">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/f00" style="margin:0.5% 0.5%;width:32.333333333333336%;float:left;">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Now, if I remove the height: 300px from column (which I am supposed to do). Then the bottom images get completely covered.

If I now remove height: 100% from homepage-main-img-wrapper and add position: relative to instagram_feed then I get this:

[image]

But my goal is to get the red images under the black image and to always get them to stary there, no matter the page size. I've tried all kinds of ways, but can't seem to get a handle on it. :/

EDIT: I updated the code with a .slide class and a script for changing the images. I actually have a carousel for the images that I originally cut of the code to save space. But this seems necessary because without position: absolute the .slide class doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `relative` and `absolute` here at all. I also think you may have a misunderstanding on how `position:relative` works. Please see : https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Hey.  I updated the code with a .slide class and a script for changing the images. I actually have a carousel for the images that I originally cut of the code to save space. But this seems necessary because without position: absolute the .slide class doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: If all your images are of the same size/aspect ratio, you can use the _padding-bottom hack_ to make the parent container span up the appropriate height despite all children being absolutely positioned.

Comment: Unfortunately, the images size changes completely depending on the page size.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute;` from `.homepage-main-img`.

The `.homepage-main-img` is absolute positioned which takes it out of the normal document flow, i.e. it won't take up space like it normally does, so the Instagram images slide up behind it.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  max-width: 1750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.homepage-main-img-wrapper {}

.homepage-main-img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #194d98;
  outline: 2px solid #0c7d5f;
}

.instagram-img {
  margin: 0.5% 0.5%;
  width: 32.333333%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <div>stuff</div>
      </div>
      <div class="column container2">
        <div class="homepage-main-img-wrapper">
          <img class="homepage-main-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/000">
        </div>
        <div id="test">
          <div id="instagram-feed" class="instagram_feed">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/f00" class="instagram-img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/f00" class="instagram-img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/f00" class="instagram-img">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey. This does seem to work, yup. But I actually originally had another class and a script for a carousel.  I didn't put it originally to have less code, but it seems critical. I updated the code with a .slide class and a script for changing the images. This seems necessary because without position: absolute the .slide class doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: @PadaKatel that's a new question. Ideally, new requirements should not be brought up after a question has been answered.